# How can I create buttons for every item in a list using a for loop and bellow a Textbox?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm creating a new window in tkinter and need to put 2 things in there. First, a textbox with elements from a list printed inside. This list contains years which will be printed  with some text concatenated.

Second, a given number of buttons bellow the textbox, this number varies and is a subset of the years printed in the text box. Text in the buttons is the year and I want to put all the buttons in a single row, the quantity of button goes from 2 to 5 depending of the list of years.

For this, I'm creating buttons with a loop, but the problem is that they are not well spaced due  to the text box in the top.

[image]

Part of code I'm using is this

```
 top = Toplevel(root)
 canvas2 = Canvas(top, width=600, height=300)
 canvas2.pack()

 header = Frame(canvas2, width=700, height=275)
 header.grid(columnspan=18, rowspan=2, row=0)

 main_content = Frame(canvas2, width=700, height=275, bg="#14a4d6")
 main_content.grid(columnspan=18, rowspan=2, row=1)


 display_text_box("\n".join(map(str, list_years_rank + list_years_result)), 0, 1, canvas2)

 for i in range(len(list_years)):
    button = Button(canvas2, text=list_years[i], font=("shanti", 10), height = 1, width = 3)
    button.grid(column=i, row=1)
```

The function display_text_box is the following:

```
def display_text_box(content, row, column, root):
    text_box = Text(root, height=6, width=50, padx=10, pady=10, fg="red")
    text_box.insert(1.0, content)
    text_box.tag_config("center", justify="center")
    text_box.tag_add("center", 1.0, "end")
    text_box.grid(column=column, row=row, padx = 25, pady = 25)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new frame for the buttons, and then put the buttons inside the frame. You'll then be able to control the spacing of the buttons independent of the grid in the window.